# World of Warcraft Private server SOAP problems

Tags: php, apache, soap

**Hello, i got some problems with my WoW Private server. Worldserver is an console for a world of warcraft private server and on the worldserver im trying to use the SOAP function to send commands from my website to the worldserver BUT i get this error when i try to use it:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Method
>   'ns1:executeCommand' not implemented: method name or namespace not
>   recognized in C:\Users\SERVER\Desktop\Crusader
>   WoW\Server\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php:33 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Users\SERVER\Desktop\Crusader
>   WoW\Server\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php(33):
>   SoapClient->__call('executeCommand', Array) #1
>   C:\Users\SERVER\Desktop\Crusader
>   WoW\Server\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php(33):
>   SoapClient->executeCommand(Object(SoapParam)) #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\SERVER\Desktop\Crusader WoW\Server\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on
>   line 33

**you can try it yourself by [visiting](http://crusader-wow.servegame.com/index.php) 
when you try to create an account you will get the error.**

**this is my index.php code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$soapUsername = 'bredegard';
$soapPassword = '123';
$soapHost = '127.0.0.1';
$soapPort = '7878';
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "ascent";
$dbname = "realmd";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

} else {
$client = new SoapClient(NULL, array(
    'location' => "http://$soapHost:$soapPort/",
    'uri'      => 'urn:TC',
    'style'    => SOAP_RPC,
    'login'    => $soapUsername,
    'password' => $soapPassword,
));

$command = "account create " . $username . " " . $password . "";

$result = $client->executeCommand(new SoapParam($command, 'command'));
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="password" style="display:none;">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I sort of remember having to setup a url onetime that had a namespace definition for something like this.  Sorry, that's all I remember, but it's to do with that.  Where is this line ` line 33` I'm to lazy to count it :)

Comment: Ah that is it, you need the WSDL file as the first parameter of the soap client, http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl - that's just general info.  See in the SoapClient constructor, you have null http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php  Where you get such a file I don't know but that is at least pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Ok thanks ill try it!

Answer (score 0):

you havent enabled soap in php.ini file open it and search soap remove the ; in front of it. Also accept it threw server